# How to delete older dump in automysqlbackup.sh

Tags: backup, mysql

I use with success automysqlbackup.sh script. All is fine. Dump's are rotate in daily/weekly/monthly folders. But is it the option to delete dump older than 3 month or sth. like that? I tried to found in script but :(

Thank you for help.

Br,

Answer (score 2):

Newer version of find include the option *-delete*, which is a better choice than using  *-exec rm {} \;*

So, if you want to automate the automatic deletion of old backups with automysqlbackup:

**1) Enable post-execution script in automysqlbackup**

Edit the configuration file /etc/default/automysqlbackup (in Ubuntu) and uncomment this line:

```
POSTBACKUP="/etc/mysql-backup-post"
```

**2) Create the file /etc/mysql-backup-post and put this code into it:**

```
#! /bin/bash

find /change/this/with/your/backup/path/ -mtime +120 -delete
```

**3) Make the file executable**

```
sudo chmod ug+x /etc/mysql-backup-post
```

NOTE: this command will ***delete*** files, so please be adviced to check the code and give a look at manpages for *find* in order to avoid unintentional deleting of important backups

Answer (score 1):

You can delete X days older files using find utility in your script.

find /path/to/files* -mtime +90 -exec rm {} \;

This will delete 90 Days old files

Answer (score 0):

This script has rotation facility in it, hope it might be helpful

http://blog.sebflipper.co.uk/2010/03/10/mysql-backup-as-separate-sql-files-with-rotation/

Comment: The link is dead.